# Codeigniter - Include javascript that is inside the application/libraries folder (script tag)

Tags: php, javascript, codeigniter

I can't come up with a solution to the following problem. Let's say i have a library (.php) file that I put inside codeigniter's library folder but that library has some javascript associated with it: I have the library "grid.php" and it has "grid.js" that comes with it. And when I load the library "grid" the

`<script src="base_url(). 'application/libraries/grid/grid.js'></script>`

is echoed in the page where I have used the grid. The problem is that the ".js" file gets forbidden access and therefore cannot be used.
I dont want to put my grid in the root level of codeigniter because I won't be able to load it with $this->load->library('grid') and I dont want move my js files manually to the root and then include them manually every time I use the grid I just want to copy and paste the grid folder to every project I need and when I use it it would include the js link automatically. Help me please :)

I saw the "Deny all" .htaccess file that resides in application and system folders but i don't want to remove that either (if it's causing the problem) :D

Comment: hi., i don't think there is the way to do access a js file from the library. but, there is another way to this to work. just put your js file in the root and create a helper function and load your library here and also load your js here like normally. Then you can call this function where ever you want. You no need to assign the js every-time. I think this may help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I saw the "Deny all" .htaccess file that resides in application and system folders but i don't want to remove that either (if it's causing the problem) :D

It's good that you don't want to remove that, it's helping to keep your application (and sensitive info like DB passwords) inaccessible over http. However, that's exactly the reason you can't access javascript files this way.

You have to bite the bullet. Move the js files into an accessible directory.

I don't see any reason why you have to write the tags out manually if you are using PHP - you might want to look into writing or adopting some kind of template/asset library that other libraries can "hook into" and dynamically add js/css to the template.

Quick example:

```
class Template {

    private $js;

    function add_js($src)
    {
        $this->js[] = $src;
    }

    function get_js()
    {
        $out = '';
        foreach ($this->js as $src)
        {
            $out .= '<script src="'.$src.'"></script>';
        }
        return $out;
    }

}
```

- Make sure Grid can access the CI instance. The most common method: assign a reference to a class property of Grid in the `__construct()`.

  ```
  $this->CI =& get_instance();
  ```
- Add the script from your Grid library:

  ```
  $this->CI->template->add_js('/path/to/grid.js')
  ```
- In your HTML template, call `$this->template->get_js()` to print the tags

Comment: I understood your point but i just wanted to have everything inside the grid folder -> the library itself the css and the js and just copy and paste this folder. So I guess I have to go with your approach. Thank you :)